# 2TB HDD - FAT32 Partition - full of *.dat files

Tags: hard-drive, windows-xp, windows-10, partitioning, fat32

I got an unusual one.

I've connected my old HDD 2TB 3,5" HDD to my laptop running Windows 10 to check my old data. I was using this HDD before with a Windows XP machine.

I can see that the HDD is full and contains the data but all of the data is in *.dat format in dirXXXX folder as you can see on the screenshot below.

[image: DIRXXX folders] | [image: *.DAT files]

HDD is formatted in FAT32 and it has only one partition. That is not correct as it would have one for the system and at least one more for the data.

Do you have any idea what would be the best way to recover the data?

Kind Regards,
Artur

Comment: Were you using some sort of disk encryption on XP?

Comment: No encryption whatsoever...

Comment: The only other thing I can think of it might be is that `CHKDISK` ran and thought everything was a lost directory/lost file and renamed those FAT chains to those names as defaults.  The every .DAT being 8K is weird though

Comment: I don't understand why it's suddenly formatted in FAT32... I am sure it was NTFS before. Is there a way co convert the filesystem without using any data?

Answer (score 0):

This could be because of backups to that drive from Windows XP or Window ME. I would go ahead with a checkdisk and if the files are not shown properly after that I would try a FAT recovery utility such as GetDataBack for FAT.

Windows XP had support for NTFS but it was not common usage. If it was your system drive then that would explain the DAT files since the OS was doing plenty of file settings wrapping in DAT files. If it was a secondary drive that could be due to corruption due to power loss and checkdisk should fix any issues you might have.

Hope this helps